# NASM to GAS Translation with intel2gas gives MISMATCH errors

Tags: assembly, nasm, gnu-assembler

I've been using nasm for quite some time but for our last exercise we were asked to translate one of our exercises in nasm to gas. I used intel2gas to convert the nasm file to gas but some parts got the **MISMATCH error.**

```
.data
MISMATCH: "        prompt db 'Enter minimum: '"
        .equ         promptLen, $-prompt
MISMATCH: "        space db ' '"

.bss
MISMATCH: "        minTens resb 1"
MISMATCH: "        minOnes resb 1"
MISMATCH: "        min resw 1"
MISMATCH: "        count resw 1"
MISMATCH: "        i resw 1"
```

Comment: You can use `.ascii` or `.byte` for the strings, and `.space` instead of `resb/resw`.

Comment: Voting to close as too broad. Please fix a single point that you can't convert. intel2gas, like most translation tools, is just a helper, and cannot handle everything.

Answer (score 2):

[gas has a complete manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/) documenting all the assembler directives you can use.  e.g. `.asciz` or `.ascii` for nul-terminated (or not) strings.

As Michael says in a comment, use `.space`, aka `.skip`, to reserve BSS space.  The `gas` manual's section on [the bss section](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/bss.html#bss) says this.